# How to align the bottom of each column in \begin{columns}?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

Option `T` is used to align the top of each column.

Is there an option to align the bottom of each column? 
If no option, how to achieve the same effect?

Note: Using option `b` is not the answer because it aligns baseline.

Comment: Please consider choosing a better username. 'LateX' could be confusing if other people like to refer to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add `\vspace{0pt}` at the end of all columns to place the baselines on the bottom as described in the answer to [Aligning image and text on top, with minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11630/aligning-image-and-text-on-top-with-minipages/11631#11631). Then the `b` option should work.