# How to put a list and an equation side by side

Tags: tables, equations, lists, vertical-alignment

I'd like to get a list and an equation side by side so that I fill the page width better for aesthetic reasons, I've tried the following but doesn't compile:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Known values:
\begin{enumerate}[i.]
\item $I_0 = 1nA = 1\cdot 10^{-9} A $
\item $T_1=20$
\item $T_2=0$
\item $T_2=100$\\
\end{enumerate}
&$I=I_0\cdot (e^{\frac{q\cdot v}{k_{bT}}}-1)$\\
\end{tabular}
```

I'm not very familiar with the tabular environment so I may have missed something or not done something necessary properly. Any help or alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `enumerate` environment would need to go into a vertical box to fix this. There are lots of ways to do this, I think the simplest is to change your column type to `p{<width>}` and then specify the `width`; I've used `.5\textwidth` below to represent 'half of the textwidth'

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{.5\textwidth}c}
Known values:
\begin{enumerate}
\item $I_0 = 1nA = 1\cdot 10^{-9} A $
\item $T_1=20$
\item $T_2=0$
\item $T_2=100$
\end{enumerate}
&$I=I_0\cdot (e^{\frac{q\cdot v}{k_{bT}}}-1)$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Other options include using a `vbox`, `minipage`, or `parbox`, but I think my displayed method is easiest (based on what you have already); explore as you see fit `:)`

As a side note, to customize any list environment, I would highly recommend the `enumitem` package, which would allow you to use

```
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\roman*.]
```

or, set it globally in the preamble using

```
\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\roman*}
```

---

For a vertically centred equation alignment, you could consider using the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array)'s `m` column specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{enumerate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{.5\linewidth}@{}p{.5\linewidth}@{}}
  Known values: \\
  \begin{enumerate}[i.]
    \item $I_0 = 1nA = 1\cdot 10^{-9} A $
    \item $T_1=20$
    \item $T_2=0$
    \item $T_2=100$
  \end{enumerate} &
  \centering $I=I_0\cdot (e^{\frac{q\cdot v}{k_{bT}}}-1)$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: @cmhughes this works perfectly however I'd like to know if there is a way to centre the equation part (so it isn't aligned with the known values but rather at the same height as 2. and 3.) as in Benedikt Bauer's answer, your syntax is shorter so I'd rather use it if possible. Great answers from both though!

Comment: @Oyibo happy to help :)

Answer (score 9):

What about putting your enumeration and equation into two side-by-side `minipages` instead of tables? As you prefer alignement of the two elements at their top, I added some top alignment (cf. [Understanding minipages - aligning at top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34166/understanding-minipages-aligning-at-top)).

Unfortunately then it is no longer possible to set the equation as displayed equation because the space above the equation would inhibit the correct alignment. This again could be fixed by putting a `\displaystyle` within the equation

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $I_0 = 1nA = 1\cdot 10^{-9} A $
            \item $T_1=20$
            \item $T_2=0$
            \item $T_2=100$
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
        $I=I_0\cdot (e^{\frac{q\cdot v}{k_{bT}}}-1)$
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer too, if I were able to accept two great answers I would have accepted both, accepted the first on the basis that it was the quickest to be posted, thanks again!

Comment: No worries, maybe it will help someone else!

Comment: I edited your post: changed `\[t\]` to `[t]`; I don't think the `standalone` package is appropriate here, but I suppose it doesn't hurt :) I changed `.49\textwidth` to `.5\textwidth` which is fine as long as you end the first `minipage` with `%` to avoid an extra space which leads to an `overfull hbox`

Comment: The ``\[t\]`` was not intended. Looks like my TeX editor did some stuff that I hadn't asked for ;-). The trick with the ``%`` at the end is really nice... Thanks for the edit!

Comment: you're welcome :) don't forget to use the `@ ` symbol when pinging someone, e.g @BenediktBauer :)