# Vertical alignment of graphic and tabular

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

There are a bunch of related questions here. But I was not yet able to pull this off yet.

I have the following code:   (where `hist.tex` is a plot drawing)

```
\fbox{\scalebox{0.40} {\input{hist.tex}}}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    p: 78\%&\\\\
    $\mu$: -7\% & $\sigma$: 7\%\\
    $\alpha$: 0.43 & N: 11977
\end{tabular}
```

The output:

[image: shot]
<sub>(source: [fc.up.pt](http://www.alunos.dcc.fc.up.pt/%7Eup200405927/trash/latex.png))</sub>

I would like them to be aligned!!

Comment: Use `[b]` position specifier for `tabular`: ---> `\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}`

Comment: Harish, thx, yours was the simpler solution .. would give you credit if you answered !

Comment: Ricardo, It is OK. Glad it helped. :)

Comment: @HarishKumar, you should make your comment an answer.  I think it's the simplest and thus the best.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Thanks for the comment but jubobs has already answered in detail. I think it is sufficient. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @RicardoCruz If you're still round, you can upload pictures to this site, then they become a permanent part of the question/answers here. Your link no longer works so anyone interested in this question cannot see your picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you want both objects aligned at the top or at the bottom, you can use two `minipage` environments and apply the [`\vspace{0pt}` trick](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/graphics/includegraphics-top-align/) to obtain the desired vertical alignment (a quirk of TeX/LaTeX).

See also [Understanding minipages - aligning at top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34166/understanding-minipages-aligning-at-top) for more details.

Set the optional argument to both `minipage` environments to

- `t` for top alignment,
- `b` for bottom alignment.

Note: I've used `tikzpicture` environment as placeholder for your graph, as you didn't provide the code for that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt}
\raggedleft
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!20] rectangle (3,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{0pt}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt}
\raggedright
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
            p: 78\%&\\\\
            $\mu$: -7\% & $\sigma$: 7\%\\
            $\alpha$: 0.43 & N: 11977
    \end{tabular}
\vspace{0pt}
\end{minipage}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Jubobs. Sorry for not posting the entire code, but I was just looking for a hint, not the full answer. :)

Comment: Anyhow, why all the spacing around the figure and the table?
http://www.alunos.dcc.fc.up.pt/~up200405927/trash/latex2.png

(I just wanted to put a figure and a table, as the transition label of a markov chain. I want them to be as compat as possible, because those markov chains can get very large ..)

Comment: Why the `\vspace{0pt}`, you mean? It's a trick to get the desired output. See the link in my answer. You can get the graph and the table pretty tight if you apply the code above. Do you need even tighter than that?

Comment: No, no. I mean, if you look at the picture in my comment .. Why is there such a big space around the graph and the table ? That is supposed to be the label of a tikz path, but it's very distant from it ..

Comment: If you would like to look at the code .. http://www.alunos.dcc.fc.up.pt/~up200405927/trash/latex.zip .. The graph & table look very distance from the transition they are associated to.

Comment: Based on the code in the .png you link to, the width of your `minipage`s is too large (half the text width!).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `adjustbox` package which does all the work without you setting any length. Just change the mock `tikzpicture` with your plot.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\section{Centered alignment}

\begin{adjustbox}{valign=c}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!20] rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  p: 78\%&\\[2ex]
  $\mu$: -7\% & $\sigma$: 7\%\\
  $\alpha$: 0.43 & N: 11977
\end{tabular}

\section{Top alignment}

\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!20] rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
  p: 78\%&\\[2ex]
  $\mu$: -7\% & $\sigma$: 7\%\\
  $\alpha$: 0.43 & N: 11977
\end{tabular}

\section{Bottom alignment}

%\begin{adjustbox}{valign=b} % adjustbox not really needed
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!20] rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{adjustbox}
\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
  p: 78\%&\\[2ex]
  $\mu$: -7\% & $\sigma$: 7\%\\
  $\alpha$: 0.43 & N: 11977
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you wanted it top or center aligned (or bottom for that matter), you would add differing amounts of vertical movement to the image.  For my example, moving the top of the image 2 and 3 `\baselineskip` of upward shift relative to the baseline was sufficient (i.e., negative below-baseline = upward relative to top of image).  Your mileage may vary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\def\x{\fbox{\scalebox{0.40} {\rule{2in}{2in}}}}
\def\y{%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    p: 78\%&\\
\\
    $\mu$: -7\% & $\sigma$: 7\%\\
    $\alpha$: 0.43 & N: 11977
\end{tabular}}
\belowbaseline[-2\baselineskip]{\x}\quad\y \par
\belowbaseline[-3\baselineskip]{\x}\quad\y
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that, if you needed a "precise" top alignment, it can be achieved with

```
\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\x}\quad\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\y}
```