# Insert image within the Exercise package

Tags: graphics, positioning, packages

I am writing an exam using `\usepackage{exercise}`. I have been using this package for some time with great results.

However, this time, I would like to insert a small image on the right side of the exercise's questions.

I've been trying several options, and finally settled for the `minipage` environment, since it is mentioned to work fine in the doc of the `exercise` package.

But I get the following unintended result

[image: not really 2 columns here]

If I replace the image with text, things work fine : I do get the 2 intended columns.

Here is a mwe

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.7\textwidth} 
\begin{Exercise}[label=ex6, origin={1.5 points}]
\Question This is question 1.
\vspace{1cm}
\Question This is question 2.
\vspace{1cm}
\Question This is question 3.
\vspace{1cm}
\end{Exercise}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth} 
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{dyn.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The `\vspace` is to allow some space for the student to write the answer.

Comment: May be Jubobs answer to [vertical-alignment-of-graphic-and-tabular](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127062/1952) can help. If not you can look in `related` or `linked` questions there.

Comment: Strangely enough, simply adding `\vspace{0pt}` just before the image allows the vertical alignment of the two columns as described by Jubobs.

Comment: This is one of TeX frequent questions which are answered in the excellent [UK List of TeX Frequently Asked Questions on the Web](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=topgraph)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the base line of the included graphics is at the bottom side of the picture and not in the middle. This could by corrected by e.g. an adapted raisebox around the includegraphics.

Another option is to use `tcolorbox` with its `sidebyside` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[blank,sidebyside,
  sidebyside gap=3mm,lefthand width=0.7\textwidth]
  \begin{Exercise}[label=ex6, origin={1.5 points}]
  \Question This is question 1.
  \vspace{1cm}
  \Question This is question 2.
  \vspace{1cm}
  \Question This is question 3.
  \vspace{1cm}
  \end{Exercise}
  \tcblower
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `lefthand width` controls the width of the exercise text. `sidebyside gap` is the distance between the left and right side. Everything below `\tcblower` is on the right side (your picture). The `\linewidth` is the resulting width for the righthand side.

Comment: This could be a useful option. But it requires yet another package (`tcolorbox`). The simpler way here is to add `\vspace{0pt}` just before the image as mentioned in the above comment. One can also increase the value from 0pt to 20pt for example to adjust the image to a lower position.

Comment: As I wrote at the begin of my answer, the problem is the position of the base line of the graphics which becomes the reference line of the minipage. If you add `\vspace{0pt}` you add a new reference position for alignment **before** the picture is inserted. The linked and related questions and answers contain similar solutions and/or raiseboxes and/or positioning with TikZ. My answer uses TikZ under the cover to align the text and the picture box centered. But there are many possible solutions.