# How to align the top of two minipages

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, minipage

I have two minipages aligned to the top of a frame (I used the option [t] on the frame and the two minipages).

If I had elements in one of the minipage, the other minipage goes down.

I have reproduced a small example ([pdf link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21594703/presentation.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
    \begin{minipage}{0.58\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{c}\hline
            \textbf{Header}    \\\hline
            \only<2->{ line2\vspace{6cm}\\\hline} 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
        \begin{block}{Text}
            text\\
        \end{block}
    \end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Do you know how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Add a `[t]`op alignment for all the components: `minipage` *and* `tabular`.

Comment: relevant information in the question [Understanding minipages - aligning at top](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34166/579)