# Strange alignment problems in longtable

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable

I have written a few environments for formatting use cases. For some reason I am having strange alignment issues in my `longtable`. I think that there is some invisible placeholder in there messing it all up, but after several hours, and after removing all unnecessary spaces, I can't find it.

Here are my environments:

```
\newenvironment{ucflowofevents}{%
\newcommand{\event}[1]{\item{##1}}%
\begin{enumerate}
}{%
\end{enumerate}
}

\newenvironment{ucentryconditions}{%
\newcommand{\cond}[1]{\item{##1}}%
\begin{itemize}
}{%
\end{itemize}
}

\newenvironment{ucexitconditions}{%
\newcommand{\cond}[1]{\item{##1}}%
\begin{itemize}
}{%
\end{itemize}
}

\newenvironment{ucrequirements}{%
\newcommand{\req}[1]{\item{##1}}%
\begin{itemize}
}{%
\end{itemize}
}

\newenvironment{pcusecase}[1]{%
    \newcommand{\row}[3][\hline]{##2 & ##3 \\ ##1}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{4cm}}%
    \newcolumntype{R}{>{\vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}\raggedright\arraybackslash}b{10cm}}%
    \newcommand{\giveninitactors}{REQUIRED!!!}%
    \newcommand{\givenevents}{REQUIRED!!!}%
    \newcommand{\givencommswith}{}%
    \newcommand{\givenentries}{}%
    \newcommand{\givenexits}{}%
    \newcommand{\givenreqs}{}%
    \newcommand{\initactors}[1]{\gdef\giveninitactors{##1}}%
    \newcommand{\commswith}[1]{\gdef\givencommswith{##1}}%
    \newcommand{\events}[1]{\gdef\givenevents{\begin{ucflowofevents}##1\end{ucflowofevents}}}%
    \newcommand{\entries}[1]{\gdef\givenentries{\begin{ucentryconditions}##1\end{ucentryconditions}}}%
    \newcommand{\exits}[1]{\gdef\givenexits{\begin{ucexitconditions}##1\end{ucexitconditions}}}%
    \newcommand{\reqs}[1]{\gdef\givenreqs{\begin{ucrequirements}##1\end{ucrequirements}}}%
    \let\givencommswith\empty%
    \let\givenentries\empty%
    \let\givenexits\empty%
    \let\givenreqs\empty%
    \centering%
    \begin{longtable}{|LR|}\hline %
        \row{Use Case:}{#1}
}{%
        \row{Initiating Actors:}{\giveninitactors}%
        \ifx\givencommswith\empty\else \row[]{Communicates With:}{\givencommswith} \fi %\hline %
        \hline\row{Flow of Events:}{\givenevents} %
        \ifx\empty\givenentries\else \row{Entry Conditions:}{\givenentries} \fi %
        \ifx\empty\givenexits\else \row{Exit Conditions:}{\givenexits} \fi %
        \ifx\empty\givenreqs\else \row{Quality Requirements:}{\givenreqs} \fi%
    \end{longtable}%
}
```

The first four just set up lists for the flow of events, entry and exit conditions, and quality requirements. But `pcusecase` sets up the `longtable`.

Notice the `\newcolumntype` definitions:

```
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{4cm}}%
    \newcolumntype{R}{>{\vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}\raggedright\arraybackslash}b{10cm}}%
```

What I really want is for them both to be top aligned, but I specified `b` for the right-hand (R) column because it exaggerates what happens. Here is my use case:

```
\begin{pcusecase}{TestUseCase}%
    \initactors{Rider, Admin}%
    \commswith{GPSService}%
    \events{\item{Event 1}%
                    \item{Event 2}}%
    \entries{\cond{Entry Condition 1}%
                     \cond{Entry Condition 2}}%
    \exits{\cond{Exit Condition 1}%
                 \cond{Exit Condition 1}}%
    \reqs{\req{Requirement 1}%
                \req{Requirement 2}
                \req{Requirement 3}}%
\end{pcusecase}
```

which gives this output:

[image: left top-aligned? right bottom aligned?]

Notice that for the first three rows, the right-hand cells are bottom-aligned like they should be, but for the remaining rows, the left cells are bottom-aligned and the right cells are top-aligned.

If I specify that left should be bottom-aligned, and the right top-aligned with

```
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}\flushleft\arraybackslash}b{4cm}}%
    \newcolumntype{R}{>{\vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{10cm}}%
```

I get this:

[image: left top-aligned? right bottom-aligned?]

The left is somehow top-aligned and the right-bottom aligned, sort of. The weirdest one, and probably the one that is going to clue somebody in, is when I specify that both should be bottom aligned and get this:

[image: WTF?]

In all three versions, the alignment in the three upper-left cells didn't change. I've been staring for hours. I need some fresh eyes on this. Your help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is the behavior is reproducible with the `article` class or do we need to try another one?

Comment: @egreg It behaves this way with article, report, and book.

Comment: Can you make a single example we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a demonstration of how the standard vertical alignment options work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \newcommand\demobox[1]{%
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[#1]{.25\textwidth}
      \tikz[baseline=(n.base)]{%
        \node (n) [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, text width=\linewidth] {Top};
        \draw [red] (n.west |- n.base) -- (n.east |- n.base);}
      \par
      This is a box with some content which should be longer than can be accommodated on one line.
      \par
      \tikz[baseline=(n.base)]{%
        \node (n) [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=base, text width=\linewidth] {Bottom};
        \draw [red] (n.west |- n.base) -- (n.east |- n.base);}
    \end{minipage}}}
\demobox{t}
\demobox{b}
\demobox{c}
\end{document}
```

[image: alignments]

The red lines mark the baselines of the first and final lines of each `minipage`. Because the first is aligned with `t` and the second with `b`, the baseline of the first line of the first and the baseline of the final line of the second are aligned. (`c` is just there fore comparison.)

The same thing happens if the alignment is with the baseline of a line of regular text:

```
This is a line of regular text across the page. Here we go\dots\par
and some text \demobox{t}
and some more \demobox{b}\par
```

[image: alignments with text]

The other complication is that `enumerate` environments, by default, include vertical spacing before the first and after the last item:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \fbox{%
    \parbox[t]{.25\textwidth}{%
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item
        \item Item
        \item Item
      \end{enumerate}}} and here is the line of text.
  \fbox{%
    \parbox[t]{.25\textwidth}{%
      Top line of text.\par Next line.\par Bottom line.}}

  \fbox{%
    \parbox[b]{.25\textwidth}{%
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item
        \item Item
        \item Item
      \end{enumerate}}} and here is the line of text.
  \fbox{%
    \parbox[b]{.25\textwidth}{%
      Top line of text.\par Next line.\par Bottom line.}}
\end{document}
```

[image: enumeration alignments]

Comment: Thank you very much for spending the time to put up this answer. In my ignorance, I assumed that a table cell was a contained environment, and that the `p`, `m`, and `b` specifications would produce top-, middle-, and bottom-aligned cells. I didn't realize that the positioning would be relative to content in adjacent cells. After reading your answer, the solution became obvious.Thanks again. When I build up enough SE cred, I'll come back and upvote your answer...

Comment: @NathanMilton It is confusing. It is because the alignments are always relative to the baseline and that will be the same, I think, for the entire row. But I kind of thought we needed a visual explanation of this somewhere because a diagram is the only way I've ever been able to grasp it ;).

Comment: Apparently a picture is also worth a thousand hours of staring stupidly at your LaTeX code. Hehehe...

Comment: @NathanMilton Always draw boxes around things when in doubt. At least, that's what I do. TeX thinks everything is a box. If you draw the boxes, it is (usually) clearer what is going on.

Comment: I provide some related explanations and illustrations in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257148/). I answer the question first so scroll down to **Explanation** if you are not interested in the specific problem ;).