# Align minipage inside minipage on top beside larger minipage

Tags: graphics, minipage

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
        Text
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.8\textwidth}
        A
    \end{minipage}%
    \llap{\begin{minipage}[t]{.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[draft]{Bild1.jpg}
    \end{minipage}}
    \par\vspace*{8pt}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
        Text
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.8\textwidth}
        B
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Can someone please explain to me why the `minipage` with `Text A` and `Text B` are not aligned to the top of the outer `minipage`?

[image: Misaligned text inside minipage]

Comment: Does [Understanding minipages - aligning at top](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34166/4301) answer your question?

Comment: If you prefer visual explanations, I drew some pictures in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241707/strange-alignment-problems-in-longtable/241868#241868. And I drew even more pictures in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257145/why-wont-m-vertically-center-my-contents/257148#257148.

Comment: I'm not really understanding why `includegraphics` sets the baseline to the bottom of the image. But I get why the minipages behave as they do. I now fixed it by adding `\vspace{0pt}` before the graphic. I don't know a better way.

Comment: The t and b options actually use the baselines of the first or last line of text (respectively).  \includegraphics is treated as a single line of text, making it both the first and last line.

Comment: For changing the position of an image on the baseline, you could have a look at the `adjustbox` package, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30079/how-to-align-picture-top-left-in-a-table