Aligning TikZ Shape and Text to the Top with Minipage
I'm writing a Go (board game) problems book — the whole project is here —, and the typical problem page goes like this:

I'm using 2 minipages plus a figure on top in order to arrange these, but, as you can see, the text isn't being aligned to the top along with the TikZ problem number. Why?
Here's something similar to what I have:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperheight   = 128mm, % ~A6
            paperwidth    = 105mm,
            bindingoffset = 5mm,
            left          = 4.5mm,
            right         = 9mm,
            top           = 15.2mm,
            bottom        = 12.2mm,
            footskip      = 6.35mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Problem Diagram

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{problemCounter}
\setcounter{problemCounter}{0}

\newcommand\problemNumber[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fontfamily{lmr}

    \node[draw,
          shape        = circle,
          inner sep    = 2.5pt,
          line width   = 0.025cm,
          minimum size = 0.45cm] 
      (char)
      {\normalsize \textmd{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\problemDiagram[1]{
  \stepcounter{problemCounter}

  \begin{figure}[t]
    \centering

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\linewidth}
      \hbox{
        \problemNumber{\theproblemCounter}
      }
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7425\linewidth}
      % \vspace{-0.67cm}
      #1
    \end{minipage}\hspace{0.5cm}
  \end{figure}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
  \problemDiagram{Here}
\end{document}

This simplified example will yield this:

I've tried using \vspace{-0.67cm} in order to force the text to the top manually, but, if the problem number gets, say, above 10, its size gets bigger, and the text gets misaligned again.
I think I'm not using the minipage package properly. How would I fix this?

Tell tikz to align the tikzpicture on the baseline of the counter number, rather than using the bottom of the picture, which is the default.
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(char.base)]


\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperheight   = 128mm, % ~A6
  paperwidth    = 105mm,
  bindingoffset = 5mm,
  left          = 4.5mm,
  right         = 9mm,
  top           = 15.2mm,
  bottom        = 12.2mm,
footskip      = 6.35mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Problem Diagram

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{problemCounter}
\setcounter{problemCounter}{0}

\newcommand\problemNumber[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(char.base)]
    \fontfamily{lmr}

    \node[draw,
      shape        = circle,
      inner sep    = 2.5pt,
      line width   = 0.025cm,
    minimum size = 0.45cm]
    (char)
    {\normalsize \textmd{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand\problemDiagram[1]{%
  \stepcounter{problemCounter}%
  \begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\linewidth}
      \hbox{%
        \problemNumber{\theproblemCounter}%
      }%
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7425\linewidth}
      % \vspace{-0.67cm}
      #1
    \end{minipage}\hspace{0.5cm}
  \end{figure}%
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\problemDiagram{Here}
\end{document}

Edit
If I've understood your comment correctly (which I'm not sure about), you actually want the top of the circle to align with the top of the text. If so, the easiest way to achieve this might be to use coffins. There is a document-level interface in xcoffins, but it is experimental, so we use the non-experimental programming layer instead. (The expl3 version is also less confusing to use.)
The basic idea is to put the circled number in one coffin and the text in another. First, we make the coffins we'll use.
\coffin_new:N \l_psygo_num_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_psygo_txt_coffin

Then we can use these in defining the command we want.  We make the first \linewidth ...
    \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_psygo_num_coffin {\linewidth}
    {
      \problemNumber{\theproblemCounter}%
    }

and the second the 0.7425\linewidth.
    \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_psygo_txt_coffin {0.7425\linewidth}
    {
      #1
    }

Then we join the second to the first, pinning them at their top right corners. This automatically gets the \linewidth and alignment desired.
    \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_psygo_num_coffin { r } { t}
    \l_psygo_txt_coffin { r } { t } { 0pt } { 0pt }

We then just spit out the result.
    \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_psygo_num_coffin { B } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }


\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperheight   = 128mm, % ~A6
  paperwidth    = 105mm,
  bindingoffset = 5mm,
  left          = 4.5mm,
  right         = 9mm,
  top           = 15.2mm,
  bottom        = 12.2mm,
footskip      = 6.35mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Problem Diagram

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{problemCounter}
\setcounter{problemCounter}{0}

\newcommand\problemNumber[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(char.north)]
    \fontfamily{lmr}

    \node[draw,
      shape        = circle,
      inner sep    = 2.5pt,
      line width   = 0.025cm,
    minimum size = 0.45cm]
    (char)
    {\normalsize \textmd{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_psygo_num_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_psygo_txt_coffin
\newcommand\problemDiagram[1]
{
  \stepcounter{problemCounter}
  \begin{figure}[t]
    \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_psygo_num_coffin {\linewidth}
    {
      \problemNumber{\theproblemCounter}%
    }
    \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_psygo_txt_coffin {0.7425\linewidth}
    {
      #1
    }
    \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_psygo_num_coffin { r } { t}
    \l_psygo_txt_coffin { r } { t } { 0pt } { 0pt }
    \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_psygo_num_coffin { B } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }
  \end{figure}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\problemDiagram{Here}
\end{document}

Edit 2
As pascal974 suggested, you can get the same result far more straightforwardly by setting baseline=0pt. However, depending on the result you want, this depends on the material in the second minipage. I understood the aim to be to align the top of the circle with the top of the minipage irrespective of the latter's content. If you instead want the top of the circle to be aligned with the height of a regular capital letter on the first line of the minipage, baseline=0pt will work. In this case, the two criteria happen to be the same, but this need not be the case.
If you have, say,
\problemDiagram{Here we have $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1+\alpha^{\frac{1}{\beta}}{\frac{23}{6^{9}}}}{y^{3}}$ and some \textsubscript{sub}scripts and \textsuperscript{super}scripts.}

then the two criteria diverge and you must use a method appropriate to the criterion you intend. Here is the result with baseline=0pt, for example,

If that's what you want, baseline=0pt will do it1. But if you intended the criterion as I interpreted it, you need a way to account for any additional height on the first line of the second minipage.
1Though I'm not sure why it is necessary since baseline=0pt is supposed to be the default according to the manual?

Is there really no way to align the text to the "topline" of the TikZ picture (not the inner number), instead of the baseline? I think the baseline looks weird for this use case.

@psygo sorry, but what do you want aligned exactly?

with baseline=0pt?

@psygo see edit. but I'm not sure whether I've understood correctly.

Just like @pascal974 mentioned, I think baseline=0pt seems to solve things.

It's super weird to me that something internal to TikZ would alter minipage's behavior. To me, minipage would look at a TikZ drawing as a black box, and then align to the top of the black box.

@psygo please see edit 2. perhaps I misunderstood you intent and baseline=0pt will do it. as I understood the desired output, it doesn't (always) do the job.

@psygo for an explanation of what's happening, please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241868/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257148/. I apologise for directing you to two answers by me, but I happened to remember I wrote them, which helps to narrow down the search quite considerably. (they are not popular answers, so maybe there are better explanations on the site. if you find one, please let me know. the second answer concerns tabular and tikzpicture. the first is more generic. tabular uses minipage for p and m columns etc., so the principles are the same regardless.)

@pascal974 please see edit 2 above. you're absolutely right you can use 0pt, which I'd forgotten, but it doesn't solve the problem as I understood it. (but the OP says it does, so I'm not sure if that's because the OP doesn't need more complex material in the second minipage or because I misunderstood the desired behaviour.)

@cfr Thank you very much for all the effort put into this answer. My case is not that complex, so I feel baseline=0pt is a good enough and simple solution. Besides, I think that, I could increase or decrease that value if something else starts bugging me.

@cfr Thanks, I learned about coffins!

@pascal974 I'm a fan ;). so much easier to align and combine!
