# How to Align Image and Table to the Top

Tags: tables, align, minipage

I want to place a table and an image side by side. I tried do this using minipage however I can't seem to find a way to align the top of the table with the top of the image. Below is my and my output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{c|*{4}{Y}}
Quadrant & 1 & 2&3&4\\
\midrule
$\sin \theta $ & + &+&-&-\\
$\cos \theta$ &+&-&-&+\\
$\tan \theta$ &+&-&+&-
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
   \vspace{-2ex}
    \includegraphics[width= 0.7\textwidth]{sign.PNG}
    \captionof{figure}{Signs of $x-$ and $y-$ ordinates}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also is there a way to automatically make the image and the table roughly the same size without manually trial and checking with the sizes?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align the minipages at the top, you use the `[t]` option. To make this work correctly with an image, put a `\vspace{0pt}` in the beginning of the minipage (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34166/understanding-minipages-aligning-at-top) for an explanation).

And to make the figure with *roughly* the same height as the table, use `\baselineskip` multiplied by the number of table rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{c|*{4}{Y}}
    Quadrant & 1 & 2&3&4\\
    \midrule
    $\sin \theta$ &+&+&-&-\\
    $\cos \theta$ &+&-&-&+\\
    $\tan \theta$ &+&-&+&-
  \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[height=4\baselineskip]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{Signs of $x-$ and $y-$ ordinates}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```