# How can I align stacked minipages horizontally?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0cm,bottom=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\raggedcolumns
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[2cm][l]{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34166/134574) to understand better how minipage alignment works. It's worth the while.

Comment: For fine tuning use \raisebox (LaTeX kernal).

Comment: You might reach a larger pool of people who can answer your questions of you don't use special fonts in your MWE.

Comment: @samcarter I edited the question. See this.

Comment: what is the proble?. beside that you set margins to zero  (why?) and forgot to insert blank line above `\vspace{2cm}` other works fine. mini pages are aligned vertically and horizontally.

Comment: @Zarko yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- to have mini pages horizontally aligned is sufficient to insert blank line before `\vspace{2cm}` (with this both groups of mini pages is indented)
- it is not clear to me, you set margins to zero . to my opinion, specila if you intent print this document, you should have minimal margins, which can prinetrs easily handle. I would use the following preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=10mm]{geometry}
\parindent=0mm
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{#1}}}
```

- i would make mini pages narrower and for distances between them insert `\hfill` (with this mini pages are uniform spread over text width

[image: \hfill]

(red lines indicate page layout).

complete mwe:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{pgffor}
    \usepackage[a4paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}
    \parindent=0mm
%    \raggedcolumns
    \newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{#1}}}

%------------- show page layout. don't use this in real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where the list will be used there is no need of margin.

Comment: Can't you use loop for minipage since each minipage contains same content?

Comment: yes, it is possible. with use of package `\usepackage{pgffor}` for example.

Comment: Then you can make short your answer using this for convenience to others.

Answer (score 1):

short answer: use `\noindent`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0cm,bottom=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\raggedcolumns
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[2cm][l]{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and if you like to have vertical space between both groups, you should insert blank line before `\vspace{2cm}` (see my comment above). actually this is sufficient to have mini pages horizontally aligned.

Comment: In your solution `\vspace` doesn't work. see @zarko's comment. zarko's solution work well.

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0cm,bottom=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\raggedcolumns
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[2cm][l]{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1.5cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]