# Horizontal align minipage doesn't work

Tags: minipage

I'm trying to align this 2 minipage on the top, but it doesn't work.....Any body help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
$2+2=4$
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

It gives me this:
[image]

I want this:
[image]

How can I get this???

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34166/121799).

Answer (score 0):

problem is position of `tikzpicture` baseline (which is in the middle of the circle). you should move it accordingly. the simplest way seems to be enclose image in `adjustbox`. a bit shorter code you obtain if instead two `minipage`s use `tabular` environment. however use of `adjustbox` work in combination with `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\centering
   \begin{tabular}{|p{0.25\linewidth}|p{0.5\linewidth}|}
$2+2=4$
&
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}% adjustbox move tikzpicture baseline to the top of tabular cell
\draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\centering
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
$2+2=4$
    \end{minipage}
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}% adjustbox move tikzpicture baseline to the line in in minipage
\draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better to use `\vspace*{0pt}` and top-align both `minipage`s (`\begin{minipage}[t]`)