# Force text in minipage to top

Tags: vertical-alignment

Hi I am trying to force text to the top of a minipage, but nothing seems to be working. I am still new to Latex do I dont know much. I am using overleaf to edit the file I put two minipages side by side, the right side is what I expect, but the left side is keeping everything in the center of the minipage. this is what the text looks like (I want B862a to go to the top of the page)

[image]

the code that is supposed to generate this part is this:

```
\documentclass{article}     
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

{
    \vspace*{\fill}                 % Posição vertical
    %\hrule                         % Linha horizontal
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}[c]{11.5cm}
            \begin{center}
                \lipsum[3]   
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{5 mm}
    \fbox{
        \begin{center}                  % Minipage Centralizado
            \begin{minipage}[]{12.5cm}        % Largura
                \begin{minipage}[t]{.1\textwidth}
                    B862a
                    \vspace{\fill}
                \end{minipage}
                \begin{minipage}[]{.80\textwidth}
                    \lipsum[2]
                    \hspace{2mm}
                \end{minipage}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
    }
    %\hrule
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your snippet compilable. I expect you want to adjust the alignment of the minipages rather than of their contents.

Comment: ok, I changed the code to something runnable outside of my original document, sorry

Comment: The code gives me an error. Does it compile for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code posted gives me an error as written. When that's corrected, I get overfull boxes, but [Peter Grill's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511676/) seems to work fine.

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass[]{article}     
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}%                 % Posição vertical
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{11.5cm}
    \begin{center}
      \lipsum[3]\bigskip
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
\bigskip\par% skips are better than absolute dimensions like 5mm when you can use them
\noindent% don't indent this paragraph
\fbox{\centering% the center environment gives an error here. Change the padding of the box or insert e.g. \smallskip\par if you want more spacing
  \begin{minipage}[]{.95\textwidth}% 12.5cm is too wide for the page layout  % Largura
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.1\textwidth}
      B862a
    \end{minipage} % note the space between the minipages here (a new line is a space unless commented)
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.80\textwidth}
      \lipsum[2]
    \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}%
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that you really don't need `csquotes` for the example.

Comment: thanks, thats exactly what I was after, I wonder why the code I posted runs on my account.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `[t]` alignment option for the `minipage` seems to work for this case:

[image]

### References

- The answers at [Understanding minipages - aligning at top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34166/4301) are a useful reference.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.1\textwidth}
    B862a
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.75\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin et blandit velit. Quisque lorem diam, aliquam sit amet nibh eu, facilisis hendrerit nulla. Nulla et auctor leo. Sed eros ligula, rhoncus a tristique ac, congue sit amet nisi. Duis semper ut mi id congue. Pellentesque ut purus vel diam posuere tincidunt. Integer luctus placerat accumsan. 
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried adding [t], but it didnt change the results

Comment: @user169808: Adding the `\t` option to both of the `minipage`s in your current MWE seems to work fine (after using the `\centering` macro instead of `center` environment). You should also use `\fbox{%` instead of `\fbox{ ` (ie, add a trailing `%`).