# text boxes with QR code, allignement problems

Tags: minipage

I need two boxes in one line which each contains a text on the left side and a QR code on its right.

As this, I started with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\begin{document}

\fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
\noindent
Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
\qrcode{https://www.wetteronline.de/wetter/duisburg}
\end{minipage}
}
\hfill
\fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
\noindent
Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
\qrcode{https://www.wetteronline.de/wetter/duisburg}
\end{minipage}
}


\end{document}
```

But this generates two problems for me:

1. The text has a lot of space on top inside each of the boxes. I want the boxes to be filled with the text and the QR code without any additional space on top.
2. both boxes are places not in a single line, they are placed mid on the page and one at top and one bellow.

Can anyone hint how to place the boxes and remove the unwanted space before the text?

I use pdflatex to create my pdf.

Comment: Why are you using `\minipage…\endminipage` instead of `\begin{minipage}…\end{minipage}`? If you don't want the boxes side by side, why do you add an empty line = new paragraph between them?

Comment: unrelated but please do not use commands like \minipage \endminipage. Use the proper environments.

Comment: Please read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34166/understanding-minipages-aligning-at-top

Comment: @cabohah: fixed the `\begin{minipage}`, also removed the stupied empty line which was really the problem. Thanks. Still open: the space in front of the text inside each of the boxes.

Comment: @cabohah: I read now also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34166/understanding-minipages-aligning-at-top, but as you see all my minipages uses the `[t]` as parameter, but text is still wrong aligned. I didn't catch the point. Need some help again!

Comment: But the baseline of a `\qrcode` is in the middle. So you have to use, e.g., the package recommended in [David Z's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34200/277964) to change the alignment of `minipage` and `\qrcode` or `\raisebox` to move the baseline.

Comment: @cabohah: I now set the minipage with the qrcode in the adjustbox and it works! Thats heavy! :-) Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\qrcode` is set with its reference point (almost) vertically centered. You can use `adjustbox` to move it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

The baseline \_\qrcode{https://www.wetteronline.de/wetter/duisburg}\_

\bigskip

\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
  Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text 
  Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text 
  Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text 
  Some dummy text Some dummy text Some dummy text
  \end{minipage}\hspace{1cm}%
  \adjustbox{valign=t}{\qrcode{https://www.wetteronline.de/wetter/duisburg}}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]