# Change the place of a figure

Tags: figure-placement

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm,mathtools,systeme}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.3cm}
\begin{document}




\noindent Let $D$ be the region bounded by the graphs of $y = x$, $y = 0$ and $x = 1$ as shown in the figure. Evaluate the following quantity:
\begin{equation*}
\int \int_{D}(x^2+3y^2+2xy)dxdy
\end{equation*}
\vspace{-0.8cm}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{int.jpg}
%\caption {\scriptsize The region $D$.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-0.8cm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes Professor @campa

Comment: Check https://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig2

Comment: Unrelated don't use `center` to center inside a float like `figure`. `center` adds vertical space around the image, so does the float. Replace `\begin{center}` by `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`.

Comment: Another comment, the line length you are using (only having 1.5cm margins left and right) makes your text very hard to read.

Comment: @daleif I think it is clear to read. What is the alternative suggestion?

Comment: Larger margins. One has to consentrate much harder to read such long lines. It is akin to reading a news paper and instead of 6 columns of text there are only two. Very annoying to read.

Comment: Where figure should be? In parallel to equation, but between paragraphs above and below equation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `adjustbox` combined with `minipages` provides more flexibility

Have a look here also -- [Understanding minipages - aligning at top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34166/understanding-minipages-aligning-at-top)

With the first `adjustbox`

[image: ![enter image description here]

Without the first `adjustbox`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

    \section{Having a picture problem?}
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
            Let $D$ be the region bounded by the graphs of $y = x$, $y = 0$ and $x = 1$ as shown in the figure. Evaluate the following quantity:
            \begin{equation*}
                \int \int_{D}(x^2+3y^2+2xy)dxdy
            \end{equation*}
    \end{minipage}}%
    \hfill
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{foo}
    \end{minipage}}
    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

`wrapstuff` is a good choice. But its documentation is in Chinese.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapstuff}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapstuff}[type=figure, width=.2\textwidth]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.jpg}
  \caption{Example Image}
\end{wrapstuff}
\noindent Let $D$ be the region bounded by the graphs of $y = x$, $y = 0$ and $x = 1$ as shown in the figure. Evaluate the following quantity:
\begin{equation*}
\iint_{D}(x^2+3y^2+2xy)dxdy
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the value of `width` key if you find the figure looks small.

Comment: Thanks. But the figure looks small.

Comment: @Student See the edited answer.

Comment: My compliments. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use paracol.  The only problem is trying to align the equation and the figure, since they don't share a baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm,mathtools,systeme}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.3cm}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}

\noindent Let $D$ be the region bounded by the graphs of $y = x$, $y = 0$ and $x = 1$ as shown in the figure. Evaluate the following quantity:

\hrule% show top
\begin{paracol}{2}
%\vfil% center in column
\begin{equation*}
\int \int_{D}(x^2+3y^2+2xy)dxdy
\end{equation*}
\switchcolumn
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption {\scriptsize The region $D$.}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-\textfloatsep}% remove padding below figure
\end{paracol}
\hrule% show bottom
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `float` package with the option **H** for the figure. An observation. The double integral code is **\iint** and not **\int \int**.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm,mathtools,systeme}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.3cm}
\begin{document}
\noindent Let $D$ be the region bounded by the graphs of $y = x$, $y = 0$ and $x = 1$ as shown in the figure. Evaluate the following quantity:
\begin{equation*}
\iint_{D}(x^2+3y^2+2xy)dxdy
\end{equation*}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{example-image-b}
%\caption {\scriptsize The region $D$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I would like the figure besides the equation since now it takes a lot of space

Comment: Than I have not understood your question. Sorry.