# How to put text in minipage top-centered?

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment, itemize, minipage, mdframed

I am working on LaTeX and R. I want to put text (here itemize top aligned) in `minipage`.

[image]

In the attached image (dummy image with `itemize` text), how can I put `itemize`

. First line
. Second line

on the top?

[image]

```
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, 
  linecolor=goldenpoppy,outerlinewidth=.5,
  innerleftmargin=8,innertopmargin=8,innerbottommargin=8]
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=.88\textwidth]{images}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{.1mm}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item first line
\item second line
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{mdframed}
```

Comment: Can you post your code you developed so far?

Comment: And please avoid excessive white space in posted images. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, you can use the [t] option with minipage to get top alignment:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
   first block of text\\
   (with multiple lines)
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
   second block of text
\end{minipage}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work here with because the text block will be aligned to the bottom of the image (from what I understand, that's the baseline of the image.)

You might take a look at [Aligning image and text on top, with minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11630/aligning-image-and-text-on-top-with-minipages), which seems to address the same question.

Comment: Yuou can do the same what @pac said, but instead of [t] write [b] and it should go to the top.

Answer (score 15):

An image is always adjusted at the bottom. In your case the line has a depth of 0pt but a height of height of image.

To change this behavior you can use the command `\raisebox`. For example

```
\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics{image}}
```

In this case the line will have height of 0pt. To align this with you right site you need a new raising by the height of `\strutbox`:

```
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox\relax}{\includegraphics{image}}
```

In this case you will get:

[image]

Here the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, 
  linecolor=orange,outerlinewidth=.5,
  innerleftmargin=8,innertopmargin=8,innerbottommargin=8]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox\relax}{\includegraphics[width=.88\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{.1mm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item first line
\item second line
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

To make the usage more user friendly you can work with the package [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox).