# Make two figures aligned at top

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, scaling

I am inserting two graphs (of different size) in the following way:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{graph1.eps}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{graph2.eps}
\caption{\label{fig:scaled_diss}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

which would be perfect if the graphs were of near-identical build, but it's currently resulting in the graph borders being mis-aligned, as in:

[image]

So the right graph doesn't have tics on the x axis.  How do I make it that the graphs are aligned at the top, then the scaling can be altered, to give something like this:

[image]

Comment: don't use scale=  use height=  so they both scale to the same height. (and don't use `H` :-)

Comment: @David But using "height=" won't give the desired result -- in the desired result, the two images do not have the same height, because of the x-axis labels in the first image.  (And for examples like the way the figures and text are used together seamlessly in the question itself, H is a reasonable way to ensure the result isn't nonsense, *if* you need to use the figure command at all. :-)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use the [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package's `valign=t` key to align the graphics contents at the top:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5,valign=t]{example-image-a}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3,valign=t]{example-image-b}
  \caption{A caption\label{fig:scaled_diss}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Using the `export` key with `adjustbox`, this will load the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package, and allow you to use its keys as part of `\includegraphics`.

Also, for your specific example, it may be more advisable to use a fixed `height`, rather than a scale. This way you can more readily provide the same vertical alignment of your items (graphics or otherwise).

Comment: I got this error: `Option clash for package adjustbox.`. Now I have to check with all other `package`s... :-(

Answer (score 21):

Since `adjustbox` is not easy to install on ubuntu-12.04 the solution proposed in [Aligning image and text on top, with minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11630/aligning-image-and-text-on-top-with-minipages) can be useful.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth}}
  \vspace{0pt} \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
  \vspace{0pt} \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: thanks. This is (at least for me) the easiest way to align the images on top. +1

Answer (score 11):

A third alternative is the `stackengine` package, with its `\belowbaseline` command, which places the top of an object a given distance below the baseline, shown below without, then with `\belowbaseline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\def\figa{\rule{1in}{1in}}
\def\figb{\scalebox{.6}{\figa}}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\figa~\figb
\caption{\label{fig:scaled_diss}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\belowbaseline[0pt]{\figa}~\belowbaseline[0pt]{\figb}
\caption{\label{fig:scaled_diss}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

And yet another alternative is to use the `graphbox`package. It has some extra options for `\includegraphics`. The top vertical aligment would be achived using `align=t` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphbox,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[align=t,scale=0.5]{example-image}
\includegraphics[align=t,scale=0.3]{example-image}
\caption{Caption text\label{fig:scaled_diss}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'd strongly advise against the use of the `float` package  `H` option. Furthermore using `\centering` rather than the environment `center` produces less vertical space.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps an even simpler one, using `multicol`:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{whatever.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.34\textwidth]{whatever.eps}
\end{multicols}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: It is best to use `\centering` instead of `center` to avoid unwanted extra white space. In addtion, try to provide full MWE, instead of just snippets that requires adding code to work. Furthermore, this solution is rather hacky and most likely not the indented way to use the package `multicol`.