# Placement of text in a table

Tags: tables, graphics, overleaf, text

So I'm making a table which will include figures, it'll look something like below

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
   Voortbewegen & \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figures/Vliegen.png} \\ \hline
   Krat neerzetten & \includegraphics[scale=1]{graphic1}  \\ \hline
   Stijfheid & \includegraphics[scale=1]{graphic1}  \\ \hline
   Vastpakken & \includegraphics[scale=1]{graphic1}  \\ \hline
   Optillen & \includegraphics[scale=1]{graphic1}  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Morfologische kaart}
\label{tab:morfkaart}
\end{table}
```

[image]

This is the output, where the text says 'Voortbewegen'it is placed at the bottom of the cell. However I want it to be in the top of the cell, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `adjustbox`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101858/47927