# Two algorithm2e environments side by side

Tags: minipage, algorithm2e

I want to get two algorithm2e environments side by side aligned at the top. I tried it with two minipages, but it does not work. How do I get them side by side in the normal text (not in a floating environment)?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,noend]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{5cm}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Algo 1}
    line 1\;
    line 2\;
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Algo 1}
    line 1\;
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\vspace{0pt}` at the beginning of each `minipage` environment. Related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11630/aligning-image-and-text-on-top-with-minipages

Comment: That doesn't work for me. `...\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\vspace{0pt}\begin{algorithm}[H]...`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need the `[t]` flag and the magic '`\vspace{0pt}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,noend]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
  \vspace{0pt}  
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Algo 1}
    line 1\;
    line 2\;
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Algo 1}
    line 1\;
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This also adds a blank line (or a vertical space of a line) at the top of the minipage (before the minipage).

Comment: @Ivo Then make the `vspaces` negative. There is no text before the algorithms in your question, so we didn't know.

Answer (score 3):

A bit different approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,noend]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\null 
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Algo 1}
    line 1\;
    line 2\;
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\null
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Algo 1}
    line 1\;
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This adds a blank line (or a vertical space of a line) at the top of the minipage (before the minipage).