# Side-by-side algorithms in two columns paper

Tags: floats, two-column, algorithm2e

I am trying to put two algorithms side-by-side on a page so it is easy
to compare their differences. I am using the `acm` template, `algorithm2e` package and `minipage` environment. but I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: [H] in two columns mode is not allowed for algorithms.
```

I have followed these steps in this post, but it dose not work out for me. [multiple algorithm2e algorithms in two column documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82271/multiple-algorithm2e-algorithms-in-two-column-documents)

Does anyone know how I can put two algorithms side-by-side?

---

This is my sample code it us work fine in one column page but it does not work in two column page.

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{8cm} 

  \null 
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    % \caption{Algo 1}

    \SetKwData{Left}{left}\SetKwData{This}{this}\SetKwData{Up}{up}
    \SetKwFunction{Union}{Union}\SetKwFunction{FindCompress}{FindCompress}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Generation step}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Initialization step}
    \Input{\color{blue} Generate } 
    \Output{ $K$}
    \BlankLine
    \Output{\color{blue}***,**}

    \emph{\bf{\color{blue} 444}}\;
    \emph{\color{blue} 2222}\;
    \emph{\color{blue}11111\;} 
    \emph{\color{blue}111\;}
    \emph{###\;
    }
    \BlankLine
    \emph{\bf{\color{blue} Received $ID$}}\;
    \For{\color {blue} each node that receives a ID}{
      \If{\color {blue} ##}{\color {blue} Add value to the list
      }
      \BlankLine
      \For{Each $received  ID$}{
        Find *,$s$\;
        \eIf{$s$ $>$ ID$}{do nothing}{Replace #}
      }
    }
    \BlankLine
    Find the smallest element on the list, $s$\;
    \eIf{$s$ $=$ $0$}{###}{*** }\BlankLine
    \BlankLine
    \caption{DNE Algorithm}\label{DNE Algorithm}
  \end{algorithm}

\end{minipage}%
\removelatexerror
\begin{minipage}[t]{8cm}
  \null

  \begin{algorithm}[H]

    \emph{**}\;
    % \Output{***}
    \emph{**}\;
    \emph{** size to 1}\;
    \BlankLine
    \emph{\bf{Broadcast}}\;
    \emph{broadcast it}\;
    \BlankLine
    \emph{\bf{Estimation}}\;
    \For{each ID$}{
      Find the smallest ,$s$\;
      \eIf{$s$ $>$ $received ID$}{do nothing}{Replace $s$ }
    }
    \BlankLine
    Find the smallest element on the list, $s$\;
    \eIf{$s$ $=$ $0$}{1111}{ab}\BlankLine
    \caption{Algorithm}\label{DNE-Algorithm}

  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you tried http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147918/17423?

Comment: Two-column floats are typeset *only* on the *top* of the page by default. Use one single float and two minipages in it.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use it. I am new in latex. do you have a sample code?

Comment: @SeanAllred yes, I got the same error with this style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `algorithm2e` does not allow `H` in twocolumn
mode, regardless if single or double float. A little excerpt from the package file:

> `\if@twocolumn\@latex@error{[H] in two columns mode is not allowed for algorithms}\fi% TODO: SCREAM if H in two colums!`

Bad thing is, for some reason two captions in an `algorithm`
environment don't work. The solution can be a quick hack, using a
`figure` and mimicking and algorithm. You have to be *very* careful
with the order of your algorithms that way. There is a pretty high chance, that the numbering gets messed up.
There might be a much
better and cleaner solution.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn
]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\begin{algorithm*}%[H]
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \rule{\linewidth}{2cm}
        \caption{left side of a pretty pretty long long
        long very very long caption}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \rule{\linewidth}{4cm}
        \caption{right side of a pretty pretty long long
        long very very long caption}
    \end{minipage}
\end{algorithm*}

\blindtext
\begin{figure*}
    \makeatletter
    \def\@captype{algocf}
    \makeatother
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \rule{.5\linewidth}{2cm}
        \caption{left side of a pretty pretty long long
        long very very long caption}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \rule{\linewidth}{4cm}
        \caption{right side}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it dose not work out, because algorithm 1 is written after algorithm 2. but I want them side by side.

Comment: @user3593321 Does that happen with the above minimal example copied pasted and compiled?

Comment: I could managed it. I followed this example and it ś working for me.http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-to-put-algorithm-and-figure-side-by-side-in-two-column-document