# Align text and image topwise

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment, align

I would like to top align an image with a text. The problem is that the text is aligned with the baseline of the image.

The current code I have is this:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}    

\begin{document}

\begin{resume}

\section{\sc Section X}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit phaedrum qualisque at. Elit honestatis interesset ut vim, tota dicunt mnesarchum te his. Vim partem voluptua maiestatis te. Vel ea diam alia inciderint, vix ad quot scribentur. Ponderum phaedrum eum ad, affert expetendis eum ne. Ei vis dictas maluisset, est volutpat contentiones ne.

\section{\sc Projects}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} lr}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} ll}
        Name: & --Name-- \\
        Type: & --Type-- \\
        Webpage: & \href{}{www.example.com}
    \end{tabular}
    &
    \vspace{0pt} 
    \includegraphics[width=1.618cm, height=1.618cm]{logo.png}
\end{tabular}

\section{\sc Section Z}
Quis zril epicurei et mel, usu soleat luptatum cu. Est ut veri convenire gubergren. Sed ad liber appareat erroribus, cum id porro error posidonium. Et eius perfecto has, mei phaedrum aliquando in, vel ponderum salutandi te. Suscipit ocurreret principes ad vis, vim id tale clita vivendum. Sale debitis persecuti pri ex.

\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

**Generated ouput:**

[image: actual_output]

**Desired output:**

[image: desired_output]

I tried doing the tabular in line *#18* like this: `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]{@{} lr}` but gives me an error. Also tried inserting `\hfill` between lines *#25* and *#26* but didn't do anything.

My approach is based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11630/aligning-image-and-text-on-top-with-minipages) previous answer.

How can achieve the desired output?

Comment: I think the adjustbox package might help

Comment: I have a simple solution based on the generic macro package `insbox`, without having the picture in a table.