# Align figures to top using minipage environment

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, minipage

I would like to align 2 figures to top using minipage environment, I've seen post like this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11630/aligning-image-and-text-on-top-with-minipages) but answers doesn't use minipage environment. I've got this code:

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
Test text
\begin{figure}[htp]
{\hfill}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
{\hfill}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}
{\hfill}
\end{figure} 


\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

I think if I've got figures align to bottom, I could align them to top. Thank you so much and excuse me if this is a duplicated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have two ways: one with minipages, one without them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X % for seeing the line width

\begin{figure}[htp]

\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{\fill}

\end{figure} 

\begin{figure}[htp]

\hspace*{\fill}%
\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill
\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\hspace*{\fill}

\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

The addition of `\vspace{0pt}` sets an invisible item at the top of the `minipage`, which becomes the the reference point.

The second solution exploits the fact that the reference point of an image is the bottom left, so raising it by `-\height` pushes it down so the reference point is the upper left.

Note the `%` to avoid spurious spaces. You're adding too many of them.

Comment: I've chosen this as best answer because it seem not be an scale issue, I've noticed what could be different sizes of images themselves, and your second option seems to be closer of get what I want, still I would like control vertical alignment. Could I switch `-\height` option to any other vertical measurement? To push down A-pic, I mean.

Comment: @JFernan Yes, any length can be used; `\height` refers to the height of the box to be raised (or lowered).

Comment: Other issue what I've got with second way is to use captions.

Comment: Adding `\vspace{0pt}` looks like a hack. Is this really intended in latex or rather a bug? Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Nikodem It's a feature: a `t`op aligned `minipage` has its reference point at the first item inside. If it's `\vspace{0pt}` the precise top left; with text it's at the baseline of the first line.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of [`graphbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphbox) package which load `graphicx` and add key `align`  to modify vertical alignment of image, in your case you need `align=t` for both.

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
Test text
\begin{figure}[htp]
{\hfill}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm,align=t]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
{\hfill}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,align=t]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}
{\hfill}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could load the `adjustbox` package which provides many facilities for adjusting content:

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
Test text
\begin{figure}[htp]
{\hfill}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
\centering
\adjincludegraphics[valign=t,scale=0.25]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
{\hfill}
\begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth}
\centering
\adjincludegraphics[valign=t,scale=0.55]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}
{\hfill}
\end{figure} 


\end{document}
```

Here I used the `\adjincludegraphics` macro instead of `\includegraphics`, with the `valign` key set to `t`. The result is as follows:

[image]